# Problem with NSDateformatter

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i've seen many questions on NSDateformatter and NSDate, but none could help me out.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/mm/dd"];
        NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:@"2010/03/10"];
        if (date) {
            NSLog(@"Date returned:::%@",date);
            return date;
        }
```

The Probelm is that, its returning the date --- '2010-01-10 00:03:00 +0600' The month is changed to 1 and the minute to 3, What might be the problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MM` for month, instead of `mm`. See the [Unicode Standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];
```

It is considering small mm to minutes that's why i guess...